# Python regarding f.tell()

Tags: python, python-2.6

I am working through a tutorial on searching an `.html` file using regular expressions (the `re` module).  I am using the interpreter.

I opened the file and preformed my search.  After each attempt, I used `f.seek(0)` to return to the beginning of the file for the next attempt.  I confirmed my location in the file using `f.tell()`.

The first few time that I did this, the location of the file (in bytes) was returned without an `L` appended to it.  But after several attempts, `f.tell()` returned the location with an `L` appended.

I understand that the `L` signifies that the file location (in `bytes`) is a `long number`.  But why would `f.tell()` suddenly begin to return the `L`, when it had not on prior occasions?

I then closed and re-opened the file, and `f.tell()` returned the `long number` from the onset?

Comment: not sure if this is what was happening, but if you do `a = 0L;print a` will give you `0` while `a` will print `0L`

Comment: Can I ask what tutorial you're working through that requires file seeking and using regular expressions to search HTML? I only ask, because it may well be if you're learning - then it could well be a *bad way to learn*...

Comment: @Andbdrew: That's because `print`ing a `0L` will show `str(0L)` (which is `0`) while just entering `a` on the interpreter command line will show `repr(0L)` which is `0L`.

Comment: Jon - I am working thru the videos and exercises in Google's Python Class (http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/set-up.html).  Has been very instructive, as I have little training as a programmer, and pursue it as a hobby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `L` signifies a `long` (which is practically only limited by the memory and computation time).

Python in general does automatic promotions of `int`s to `long`s as soon as the value exceeds the range the `int` type can handle.  Also, if some operation with another `long` takes place, the result always is a `long` (`0 + 0L` → `0L`).

In your case I can only speculate what caused this effect.  Maybe reading beyond a certain limit caused the promotion, maybe some internal handling (which does not always take place) was the reason.

I don't think that it will matter to you.

Comment: It's "promotes" not "upgrades" :) But yes, not something the OP should worry about

Comment: Thanks.  I was curious as to what would cause the change in behavior.  I appreciate your feedback.